# Problem when running insert-sample <login> <pwd>

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

I'm exploring DocdokuPLM.

To Install docdoku I have used the docker configuration file which can be found [here.](https://github.com/docdoku/docdoku-plm-docker)

Using it have configured and installed Docdokuplm in my localhost.
Now not sure why sample project is not getting imported.

To import and check sample project I have used the following command.

```
sudo ./platform-ctl insert-sample MY_LOGIN_USER_ID MY_PASSWORD
```

While running the command to import sample project i'm getting the following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Total time: 16.571 s 
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-01-31T07:29:36+00:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 34M/301M 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] - No workspace name supplied, generating one... 
[INFO] - Using wks-a72fca63 as workspace name  
[INFO] - Starting load process...  
[INFO] - Checking server availability... 
[INFO] - Creating your account... 
[INFO] - Creating account [sommesh29] 
[INFO] - Cannot create account, trying to use given credentials for next operations 
[INFO] - Creating workspace... 
[INFO] - Adding user sommesh29 to workspace wks-a72fca63 
[SEVERE] - Ooops, something went wrong while loading sample data : Not Found Not Foundcom.docdoku.api.client.ApiException: Not Found
    at com.docdoku.api.client.ApiClient.handleResponse(ApiClient.java:838)
    at com.docdoku.api.client.ApiClient.execute(ApiClient.java:773)
    at com.docdoku.api.client.ApiClient.execute(ApiClient.java:757)
    at com.docdoku.api.services.WorkspacesApi.addUserWithHttpInfo(WorkspacesApi.java:833)
    at com.docdoku.api.services.WorkspacesApi.addUser(WorkspacesApi.java:819)
    at com.docdoku.loaders.SampleLoader.addUserToWorkspace(SampleLoader.java:304)
    at com.docdoku.loaders.SampleLoader.load(SampleLoader.java:88)
    at com.docdoku.loaders.Main.main(Main.java:73)
```

what am i doing wrong ?

Is this a issue from my side or is this issue occurring from Docker file?